Jupyter Notebook Doubles Count of Executable Cells - Numbering of Cells on Left is OK
I've noticed that when I run one cell in a Jupyter notebook, the progress indicator says I'm executing two cells when I'm only actually executing one.  If I restart the kernal and run all cells, even though there are a total of 22 cells, the notebook says it's running 46 cells.
This started happening recently.  I researched the problem and noticed that people were having an issue with the number count on the left side of each cell skipping every other number.  This is not happening to me - those numbers are correctly sequential.  It just seems the notebook thinks it has more cells to execute and continues to be 'busy' long after my actual cells have run.
I am newer to Jupyter and Python fyi.
I've tried restarting the kernal and restarting jupyter lab. I tried running a cell in a brand new notebook, when I run one cell, the notebook says it's executing two of them.  It looks to be happening in other kernals as well.

Hmmm... I suspect it is still the same issue as here though. It is too similar to not be related, I suspect. A major point you leave out of your post is whether you are using this with Anaconda or not? That would either make it seem more likely or rule it out.

Yes I am using this with Anaconda.  I use GitBash to navigate to where I want and then run jupyter lab on the command line.
I tried the line of code mentioned in the issue you linked to, then restarted my notebook.  It did not fix the issue.  It'll run through ~22 cells, but it says it actually executes 46 cells and it takes about 10 seconds for each one.

Are you sure that disabled the AI?

I am not sure how to check.  I've never had sparkles next to my jupyter notebook cells.
I ran jupyter labextension disable @anaconda/assistant and received no output, just back to command line.  I restarted Jupyter Lab, even rebooted my computer, but the issue still occurs.

Sparkles means the AI is still running. Whatever you did to disable it, you haven't fully propagated the changes.( Often you need to restart or at least do a hard refresh on the page. In Chrome on a Mac that is Shift+R and on Windows I think it is Shift + F5 .) Or you didn't pick the right way yet to disable it?

I use Chrome on Windows and I believe it's Ctrl + F5.  Still happening.  I appreciate the help so far.

I'm out of things to suggest, but if sparkles are there, I think it is still running. It is possible they changed name since updated, I suppose.

I've never had sparkles before or after this issue.  If I can find a solution, I will update this.

Slowly learning how this stuff works, so bear with me.  I believe I've found the issue.

Ran Jupyter Lab in safe mode.  My notebook ran exactly the amount of cells it was supposed to.
Googled how to disable lab extensions and to even figure out what I even have.  It's not something I've had to pay attention to before.
After some trial and error, I discovered that it's the jupyterlab_variableinspector so I ran the command jupyter labextension disable @lckr/jupyterlab_variableinspector, restarted my notebook and it ran normally.

I don't know why I have this though.

Excellent sleuthing! I'll keep my eyes open. A quick look at the issues page for it didn't have anything jump out at me; however, it may very well be buried in there. Or you are the first to uncover it. Or something was a bit off in the way it installed on your machine. We'll see. Glad it isn't plaguing you now.

Thank you for your help!  Your posts about labextenstions taught me something new and pointed in the right general direction.

Steps on how I fixed the issue.

Ran Jupyter Lab in safe mode. My notebook ran exactly the amount of cells it was supposed to.

jupyter lab --safe-mode

Listed all my labextensions and disabled them one at a time, restarting the notebook after each to isolate the culprit.

jupyter labextension list
jupyter labextension disable <extension-name>

After some trial and error, I discovered that it's the jupyterlab_variableinspector so I ran the command jupyter labextension disable @lckr/jupyterlab_variableinspector, restarted my notebook and it ran normally.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
